# Spotify List objects created from localStorage data come up blank

Tags: html, local-storage, spotify

I'm working on a Spotify app and trying to create a views.List object from some stored information in our database.  On initial load, a POST is made to get the necessary info.  I store this in localstorage so each subsequent request can avoid hitting the database and retrieve the object locally.  What's happening though is the List objects I create from localstorage data come up blank, while the POST requests work just fine.

Here is the snippet I'm using to create the list:

```
var temp_playlist = models.Playlist.fromURI(playlist.uri);
var tempList = new views.List(temp_playlist, function (track) {
    return new views.Track(track, views.Track.FIELD.STAR |
                views.Track.FIELD.NAME |
                views.Track.FIELD.ARTIST |
                views.Track.FIELD.DURATION);
});

document.getElementById("tracklist").appendChild(tempList.node);
```

playlist.uri in the first line is what I'm retrieving either from a POST or from localstorage.    The resulting views.List object (tempList) looks identical in both cases except for tempList.node.  The one retrieved from localstorage shows these values for innerHTML, innerText, outerHTML, and outerText in console.log:

```
innerHTML: "<div style="height: 400px; "></div>"
innerText: ""
outerHTML: "<div style="height: 400px; "></div>"
outerText: ""
```

Whereas the one retrieved via POST has the full data:

```
innerHTML: "<div style="height: 400px; "><a href="spotify:track:07CnMloaACYeFpwgZ9ihfg" class="sp-item sp-track sp-track-availability-0" title="Boss On The Boat by Tosca" data-itemindex="0" data-viewindex="0" style="-webkit-transform: translateY(0px); ">....
innerText: "3Boss On The BoatTosca6:082....
```

and so forth..

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using, the local storage, I did it this way :

```
sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var m = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var v = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/views");

var pl;
pl = m.Playlist.fromURI(uri);
var player = new v.Player();
player.track = pl.get(0);
player.context = pl;
var list = new v.List(pl);
XXXXX.append($(list.node));
```

Hope, it will help, as it's working for me

Comment: This works, but only on the first load.  What my app is doing is changing arguments to index:id and loading the playlist associated with that specific id.  If I load another playlist (by changing the arguments) and load the original one again, the original will show up blank.

Comment: I get a similar issue when I tried to rotate article on top list. It looks to be a drawing issue when it calls the ajax playlist loading. Did you try to put the `pl.get(0)` first track ?

Comment: Yes, tried pl.get(0) and didn't help.  You are right about the drawing issue, if I resize the Spotify application when the "blank" tracklist is there, the tracks render properly.  Saw this mentioned in a very similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387360/spotify-app-api-tab-pages-playlist-ui-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Solved this.

I am using hide() and show() to render the tabs in my app.  I was constructing the tracklist and then show()ing the div which led to a blank tracklist.  If I simply show() the div and then construct the tracklist it works fine.

The reason (I think) it was working for POSTs is because the tracklist was retrieved from the database and the slightly longer loading time probably meant the tracklist was constructed after the div's show() executed.  With localStorage I guess the tracklist was constructed before the div was even shown, leading to the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've actually managed to solve this and I think it's bulletproof.

Basically I was trying to solve this by trying to convince the API that it needed to redraw the playlist by hiding things/scrolling things/moving things which worked occasionally but never consistently. It never occurred to me to change the playlist itself. Or at least make the API think the playlist has changed.

You can do so by firing an event on the Playlist object.

```
var models = sp.require('$api/models');

...

// playlist is your Playlist object. Usually retrieved from models.Playlist.fromURI
playlist.notify(models.EVENT.CHANGE, playlist);
```

These are just standard Spotify functions and the list updates because it thinks something has changed in the playlist. Hope this helps someone!